# How to apply jQuery styles to a button?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [**jQuery Button**](http://jqueryui.com/button/) and have the following:

HTML:

```
<input class="test" type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check">Toggle</label>
<input class="test2" type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Hello</label>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#check" ).button();
});
$(function() {
  $( "#check2" ).button();
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-button .test {
    font:  12px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0;
    padding-top: 55px;
    background-image: url(graphics/move.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size: 48px 48px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 #888;
    background-position:center 10px;

}
```

I used `.ui-button .test` for one button but the CSS is not working.

Comment: Use comma as `.ui-button, .test`

Comment: Where is you `.ui-button` element? Otherwise `.test` won't do anything.

Comment: Please first write your full code here. Where is .ui-button element?

Comment: @speetje33 and @dirtyhandsphp: the `ui-button` class is applied to an element by jQuery UI when an element is targeted with the `button()` function.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: `.ui-button, .test` applies styles to elements with either class. therefore also applying the style to the element with the `test2` class which is not what is required. The style needs to be applied to an element which has both classes not just one of them instead, i.e: `.ui-button.test`. which then will not apply the style to the `.test2` element as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in this fiddle the button element is not created around the current element. The current element is hidden and a new one is created:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/KGq56/1/

To style the button differently you would need to change the CSS, or apply a custom class to the button after it has been created such as http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/KGq56/8/:

`$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button().next().addClass("test");
});`

However, it is easier to change the HTML to the following with the class applied to the label, not the input http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/KGq56/9/:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check" class="test">Toggle</label>
```

then you would only need to do the following:

`$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button();
});`

Then you can use the class selector `.ui-button.test` to style it appropriately.

Comment: Yes, the `input` element is hidden as jQuery UI applies the class `ui-helper-hidden-accessible` to it. However, that a new element is created is not strictly just like that. The `<label>` element of the `<input>` is used and **must** exist in the first place. Only then a new `<span class="ui-button-text">Toggle</span>` element is created with the text from the hidden `<input>` and injected into the pre-existing `<label>` element. Without the `<label>` there will be be no element created.

Comment: @user3422998: Instead of using `addClass()` you can also just assign the class directly to your label as that is the element jQuery UI uses: `<label class="test" for="check">Toggle</label>`. see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vdfL/). There is no need for additional complexity and script execution if you can have the default markup as required.

Comment: Good spot there Francois, in both cases. I hadn't realised the button function updated the label element rather than the input, but a look at the generated source proves it is so. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Alex: +1 for nice detailed answer and explanations. While I had the CSS correct (`.ui-button.test`) in my answer I failed to spot that the `test` class was on the `input` and not the `label`. So I deleted my answer and will vote yours up instead :)